# SNS Topic says it wants a string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have looked around through several guides and they all follow this same pattern, yet I still get the following error:

```
An error occurred: IngestSNSTopic - Value of property Endpoint must be of type String.
```

Using the serverless framework here is the section that declares that resource.  I have been going over and over this for a few hours now, would love some help, thanks.

```
    IngestSNSTopic:
      Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
      Properties:
        Subscription:
          -
            Endpoint:
              Fn::GetAtt:
                - IngestQueue
                - Arn
              Protocol: sqs
    IngestQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${opt:stage}-mam-ingest-queue-${file(env/${opt:stage, 'dev'}.yml):IP_SLUG}
        RedrivePolicy:
          maxReceiveCount: 3
          deadLetterTargetArn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - IngestDeadLetter
              - Arn
```

Comment: Stack deployed fine before I included the SNS stuff

Comment: Hard to tell but it looks like the YAML for the `IngestSNSTopic` is indented too much? Is it valid YAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [AWS docs are actually incorrect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html), the JSON and YAML examples differ in output. The `Protocol` property is indented once too many, which means `Endpoint` would evaluate as an object.

Here is what your config evaluates to in JSON:

```
{
    "IngestSNSTopic": {
        "Type": "AWS::SNS::Topic",
        "Properties": {
            "Subscription": [
                {
                    "Endpoint": {
                        "Fn::GetAtt": [
                            "IngestQueue",
                            "Arn"
                        ],
                        "Protocol": "sqs"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I think it should be:

```
    IngestSNSTopic:
      Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
      Properties:
        Subscription:
          -
            Endpoint:
              Fn::GetAtt:
                - IngestQueue
                - Arn
            Protocol: sqs
```

Comment: Looking good so far! I almost tried that earlier but every single guide had it the other way!

Comment: The mistake in the docs is misleading but the error from the platform is correct, `Endpoint` needs to be a string. Messages from the platform can be vague leading to general mistrust but in this case it's the best clue.